# glsl (es) float division performance

Tags: glsl, glsles

The simple question. 
Is glsl/es float div operation MUCH slower than mul? I know it slower on x86, but is it slower on GPU? 
When I look at GLSL disassembler I just see one more "rcp" command and all. How much costs that "rcp"?

Comment: The "Estimating program costs" section of https://static.docs.arm.com/dui0363/d/DUI0363D_opengl_es_app_dev_guide.pdf#G7.1568767 might help (at least for ARM Mali GPUs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It varies from GPU to GPU, but in most cases, an rcp (reciprocal) instruction is roughly as expensive as a mul instruction.  A divide ends up being roughly as expensive as a mul + an rcp.  Both are fairly cheap compared to a texture lookup or branch of any kind.

Comment: Is there somewhere table with costs of each command in cycles?

Comment: @tower120 I suspect there's none because each vendor implements those differently. Your glsl is compiled by a driver so it will not make any difference from your perspective. You cant influence what driver does.